# Proving a function (involving Erf) has a unique real root

Tags: analysis, probability-distributions, special-functions

I am trying to prove that the following function:

$$g(x) = x - \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \frac{\operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{1-\operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2} $$

where $\operatorname{Erf}$ is the Error function, has a unique real root (i.e. $g(x)=0$ has a unique real solution) at $x=0$.

Visual inspection with WolframAlpha: http://wolfr.am/1iXZ5LB

**One candidate way** to prove this would be to prove that $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $g(x)<0$ for $x<0$ (seemingly true by visual inspection), but I can't seem to find appropriate inequalities that help me establish this.

**A second candidate** way to prove this would be to prove that the derivative $g'(x)$ is always positive (WolframAlpha visual inspection: http://wolfr.am/KJhoFz), since this would establish that g(x) only crosses $x=0$ once. Again, I can't seem to figure out a way to prove this.

**A third candidate** way would be to use that $g(x)$ is odd (easy to see/show), and thus only has non-zero coefficients in its Taylor expansion at $x=0$, $g(0) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$, for odd $n$. If $g^{(n)}(0)$ is non-negative for all odd $n$ then the function has only one real root, at $x=0$. But I don't see a way to prove that all the odd coefficients are non-negative.

I'm wondering if anyone sees any tricks involving Erf, or more general tricks, for analytically proving this fact (that I'm very convinced is true by visual inspection).

Comment: The conversation in the answer proposed below has uncovered the following inequalities: $e^{-\frac{2}{\pi}x^2} \le 1-Erf(x/\sqrt 2) \le  e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. But no proof yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another thought. The only two pieces of that function that change sign are $x$ and $\mathrm{Erf}(x/\sqrt{2})$. Both change sign at 0. So, it comes down to showing that

$$
x < \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} \frac{\mathrm{Erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{1-\mathrm{Erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}
$$

when $x < 0$

and

$$
x > \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} \frac{\mathrm{Erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})}{1-\mathrm{Erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2}
$$

when $x > 0$

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is essentially the approach of my first candidate approach. Unfortunately the non-constant "factor" $(e^{-x^2})/(1-Erf(x/\sqrt 2 )^2)$ makes it more than merely a comparison of $x$ and $Erf(x/\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: And to boot $e^{-x^2} \geq 1 - \mathrm{Erf}(x/\sqrt(2))^2$ (though not by a whole lot)

Comment: Oops, I typo'd above: the "factor" is of course $e^{-x^2/2}/(1-Erf(x/\sqrt{2})^2)$, and I believe your observation is for $e^{-x^2/2}$ on the LHS as well.

Comment: Yes, although one could just ditch the $\sqrt{2}$ by letting $x \rightarrow \sqrt{2}x$...

Comment: Yes, that's possible, and in fact the following is true: $e^{-x^2} \le 1 - Erf(x/\sqrt 2)^2 \le e^{-x^2/2}$. But I haven't been able to use it to finish the proof...

Comment: By using the inequalities in the above comment applied the the derivative $g'(x)$, I believe I've been able to show that $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$, the second candidate approach above. Answer forthcoming, thanks for the help!

Comment: I wait with baited breath

Comment: Sadly: False alarm, no proof yet. The equations here leave very little room to spare, very frustrating....